# Can I safely stop the decommission of a Cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra

Is possible to rollback / cancel a `nodetool decommission` if something goes wrong on the other nodes or on the clients?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The decommission process is designed to work that way. You can just stop the decommissioning node, restart it, and everything should continue as normal.

Note that any data streamed will now be present on its (former) target nodes.  If you end up not proceeding with the decommission process, you may want to run a `nodetool cleanup` on those nodes just to make sure they only contain data that they're responsible for.  But the data on the original node will not be removed or lost.